# Constraint manipulation package

Tags: haskell, type-constraints

Lets say I have

```
class C1 t
```

and

```
class C2 t
```

note here that:

```
C1 :: * -> Constraint 
C2 :: * -> Constraint
```

I can make

```
class (C1 t, C2 t) => C3 t
instance (C1 t, C2 t) => C3 t
```

So we have

```
C3 :: * -> Constraint
```

noting that `C3 t` is only valid if `C1 t` and `C2 t` is.

Furthermore, if we add a bunch of extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableSuperClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
```

We can even do something more general like this:

```
class (c1 a, c2 a) => And c1 c2 a
instance (c1 a, c2 a) => And c1 c2 a

type C3 = C1 `And` C2
```

And this works as expected.

This is not the only combination of constraints I want to be able to do, for example, I'd like to be able to combine constraints of two variables, say `And2`:

```
class (c1 a b, c2 a b) => And2 c1 c2 a b
instance (c1 a b, c2 a b) => And2 c1 c2 a b
```

Or add an extra constraint to the first variable:

```
class (c1 a, c2 a b) => AddFirst c1 c2 a b
instance (c1 a, c2 a b) => AddFirst c1 c2 a b
```

There's lots of possibilities of course.

Now not wanting to reinvent the wheel, I was looking at the [constraints](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package, from which I quote:

> ConstraintKinds made type classes into types of a new kind, Constraint.

```
Eq :: * -> Constraint
Ord :: * -> Constraint 
Monad :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
```

> With ConstraintKinds we can put into code a lot of tools for
>   manipulating these new types without such awkward workarounds.

This seems like it fits the bill but I kind got lost in the documentation.

Does the `constraints` package do what I've set out in this post? If so, could you provide an example? If not, is there any other package for constraint manipulation, or should I fill this out into a library myself?

Answer (score 2):

In [generics-sop](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop), this kind of constraint manipulation is often needed, because a considerable number of its functions are parameterized over constraints.

The library therefore contains a module [`Generics.SOP.Constraint`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.2.4.0/docs/Generics-SOP-Constraint.html) with a number of these helper classes, in particular your `And`. More could in principle be added if they turn out to be generally useful.

As far as I know, the constraints library is primarily concerned with a slightly different problem, namely giving you an explicit representation of dictionaries and entailment, providing you with utilities to prove things about type classes that GHC cannot automatically prove. It is certainly possible to combine constraints with this library as well, for example via [`(&&&)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.9/docs/Data-Constraint.html#v:-38--38--38-). Again, generics-sop has similar functionality as well (although it has far fewer functions, and aims to do less), in [`Generics.SOP.Dict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.2.4.0/docs/Generics-SOP-Dict.html).